# How to change marker position to the pasted address location in Google maps api?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am new to google map . So i need your idea to implement google map.

My question is :

Is there any way to move the marker to the address in search field without hitting enter / clicking .

I had included the example to show the working of normal positioning of marker in google map.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

My idea is ... copy the address and paste it in places search box. After pasting, it need to be move the marker to the pasted address co-ordinates. Here, i dont want to hit any button/ mouse to move the marker.

Sorry for my bad language.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to detect a paste event in a text field:

```js
$("#textA").bind('paste', function() {
    console.log($("#textA").text());

    // update your place address with that value
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... But can you give me an example for this idea ?